# Is it normal for a newborn to develop pimples?

Tags: newborn, health, skin-care

My daughter is 2 weeks old and has developed a pimple like rash on her forehead. 
Is this a common problem for new babies? 
What things (if any) can I do to alleviate the problem?

Comment: My 2 week old daughter has such a rash - it started on her forehead three days ago, spread to cheeks and eyelids, but seems to be slowly disappearing already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is common! Just wash with water and a soft cloth. "Baby acne occurs when hormonal changes in the body stimulate oil glands in the baby's skin. The condition can look worse when the baby is crying or fussy, or any other instance that increases blood flow to the skin. Baby acne is harmless and usually resolves on its own within several weeks" (Medline Plus, National Institute of Health).  It lasted about 2 weeks with my firstborn.

Answer (score 1):

Newborns are exposed to all the intense hormones of labor that flooded through the mother's system and made birth possible. It gives the baby acne that can last for a while. Talk to your pediatrician if you're worried, but it's pretty standard for the acne to show up within a week or two of birth. My son had it all over his chest. You don't need to do anything to their delicate baby skin, just give it time.